# JavaScript/CSS vs. Silverlight vs. Flex

Tags: javascript, apache-flex, silverlight, web-applications, user-interface

We currently have a quite complex business application that contains a huge lot of JavaScript code for making the user interface & interaction feel as close to working with a traditional desktop application as possible (since that's what our users want). Over the years, this Javascript code has grown and grown, making it hard to manage & maintain and making it ever more likely that adding new functionallity will break some existing one. Needless to say, lots of this code also isn't state of the art anymore.

Thus, we have some ongoing discussion whether the client-side part of the application should be written anew in either Flex or Silverlight, or written anew with some state of the art JavaScript framework like jQuery, or whether we should simply carry on with what we have and gradually try to replace the worst bits of the existing code. What makes this even harder to decide is that writing the UI anew will probable cost us 6-12 person months.

I'd like to hear your thoughts on that issue (maybe some of you have already had to make a similar decission).

EDIT: To answer some of the questions that came up with the answers: The back-end code is written in C#, the target audience are (usually) non-technical users from the companies we sell the software to (not the general public, but not strictly internal users either), the software 'only' has to run in desktop browsers but not necessarily on mobile devices, and the client app is a full-blown UI.

Comment: Does the current code use any Javascript frameworks?

Comment: Since the code is old, we've developed our own framework (sort of ;-) over the time, but we don't use any standard JS framework.

Comment: Answer expanded based on extra information (see below).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In all honesty, I would refactor the old JavaScript code and not rewrite the application.  Since you are asking about which platform to put it in, I would guess that your team isn't an expert in any of them (not slamming the team, it's just a simple fact that you have to consider when making a decision).  This will work against you as you'll have double duty rewriting and learning how to do things on the new platform.

By keeping it in JavaScript, you can slowly introduce a framework if you choose and do it iteratively (Replace on section of code, test it, release it, and fix any bugs).  This will allow you to do it at a slower pace and get feedback along the way.  That way too, if the project is canceled part way through, you aren't out all the work, because the updated code is being used by the end users.  Remember the waterfall model, which is essentially what a full swap out of will be almost never works.

As much as I hate to admit this, as it is always the most fun for developers, shifting platforms, and replacing an entire system at once rarely works.  There are countless examples of this, Netscape for one.  [Here is the post from Spolsky on it.](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000027.html) (I would also recommend the book [Dreaming in Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1400082463). It is an excellent example of a software project that failed and how and why).  Remember to rewrite a system from scratch you are essentially going to have to go through every line of code and figure what it does and why.  At first you think you can skip it, but eventually it comes down to this.  Like you said, your code is old, and that means there are most likely hacks in it to get something done.  Some of these you can ignore, and others will be, "I didn't know the system needed it to do that."

Comment: What's more, moving to a rich client technology like Silverlight or Flex will likely require many more application changes than swapping out your hand-rolled JS framework with a standard one. It might be difficult to reproduce the style of your HTML app in Flex/Sliverlight, etc.

Answer (score 5):

This decision is usually less about the technology, and more about your skill sets and comfort zones.

If you have guys that eat and breathe Javascript, but know nothing about .net or Flash/Flex then there's nothing wrong with sticking with Javascript and leaning on a library like jQuery or Prototype.

If you have skills in either of the others then you might get a quicker result using Silverlight or Flex, as you get quite a lot of functionality "for free" with both of them.

Answer (score 5):

These things spring to mind:

- As you have a .Net backend and you have some ability to force your customers onto a specific platform, Silverlight is an option;
- Since your client is a full-blown UI you want widgets and possibly other features like Drag and Drop;
- I haven't seen any requirements that to me would justify starting over (which often doesn't work out) in Flex/Silverlight (eg streaming video, SVG support.  Added to your team's familiarity with Javascript, I think you can't make a compelling case for doing it in anything other than Javascript.

But of course Javascript is lots of things and there are [lots of Javascript frameworks[1](http://ui.jquery.com/demos).  The most important divider is whether your intent is to "decorate" a set of Web pages or you need a full set of Widgets to create a desktop-like application on the Web.  Your question indicate it is the latter.

As such--and I may get downvoted for saying this--I don't think jQuery is the answer and I say this as someone who loves jQuery.  jQuery (imho) is great to enhance Webpages and abstract cross-browser low-level functionality but the most important factor for complex UI developer is this:

**It's all about the widgets.**

And yes I'm aware of [jQuery UI](http://ui.jquery.com/demos) but it's a lot sparser than the others when it comes to widgets.  I suggest you take a look at the samples and widget galleries of some frameworks:

- [YUI Examples Gallery](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/);
- [ExtJS demo](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/samples.html); and
- [SmartClient feature explorer](http://www.smartclient.com/index.jsp#_Welcome).

The others (jQuery, Dojo, Mootools, Prototype) are more "compact" frameworks arguably less suited to your purpose.

Also consider the license of each framework when making your decision.

My thoughts on the above three are:

- ExtJS has somewhat angered the community in that it started out as LGPL but had a [controversial license change](http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33096) (that thread is at 76 pages!) to GPL/commercial at version 2.1.  The problem with that the community no longer has an active participation in the framework's development.  Not the mainline version anyway.  This means it's being developed and supported by a small team (possibly one person) rather than the community.  IMHO it's not worth paying a commercial license for that and GPL is probably prohibitive in your situation;
- YUI is supported by Yahoo and available under a far more permissive and far less invasive BSD license.  It's mature, well-used and well worth serious consideration; and
- SmartClient impresses me a lot.  It has perhaps the most permissive license of all (LGPL), is roughly seven years old, has an incredibly impressive array of widgets available.  Check out their feature explorer.

Your decision should be based on how you get as much of your application "for free" as possible.  You don't want to spending valuable developer time doing things like:

- Coding UI widgets like trees and accordions;
- Testing and fixing cross-browser Javascript and CSS issues;
- Creating homegrown frameworks that greatly duplicate what existing frameworks do and do well.

I would seriously look at one of the above three as your path forward.

Comment: Good points - I've edited my question to answer those details.

Comment: nitpick: BSD licenses are far more permissive than LGPL

Answer (score 4):

My opinion on this one's pretty simple: unless the app needs to be accessible publicly, unless it needs to be search-engine optimized and findable, and/or there's an otherwise compelling case for its having to remain strictly text-based, then the chips are stacked in favor of rich-client runtimes like Flash or Silverlight right out of the gate.

A big reason, if not the biggest, is that they eliminate the complexities of developing for multiple browsers and platforms.  Again: they **eliminate the runtime-environment variable**.   No more debugging old versions of Netscape and IE, no more object detection and consequent branching, no more wacky CSS hacks -- one codebase, and you're done.  Offloading the runtime environment to Adobe or Microsoft will save you time, money and headaches, all else equal.  (Sure, there's YUI, JQuery, etc., but they don't eliminate that variable -- they just abstract it.  And they don't abstract *all* of it, either -- only some of it; ultimately, it's still up to you to test, debug, retest, debug, repeat.)

Of course, your situation's a bit more complicated by the existing-codebase problem, and it's difficult to say definitively which way you should go, because only you've got the code, and we're just geeks with opinions.  But assuming, just by your asking the question, that a refactoring of your existing codebase would involve a significant-enough undertaking as to warrant even considering an alternative (and probably comparatively foreign) technology in the first place, which it sounds like it would, then my response is that your curiosity is well-placed, and that you should give them both a serious look before making a decision.

For my part, I'm a longtime server-side guy, ASP.NET/C# for the past several years, and I've written many a text-based line-of-business app in my time, the last few with strong emphasis on delivering rich soverign UIs with JavaScript.  I've also spent the last couple of years almost exclusively with Flex.  I've got experience in both worlds.  And I can tell you without hesitation that right now, **it's everyone else's job to beat Flex**:  it's just an amazingly versatile and productive product, and for line-of-business apps, it remains leaps and bounds ahead of Silverlight.  I just can't recommend it highly enough; the data-binding and event-handling features alone are incredible time-savers, to say nothing of the complete freedom you'll have over layout, animation, etc.  The list goes on.

So, my advice:  **take a long, careful look at Flex**.  In the end, you might find a ground-up rewrite is just too massive an undertaking to justify, and that's fine -- only you can make that determination.  (And to be fair, you've just as much ability to make a mess of a Flex project as you do with a JavaScript project -- I know.  I've done it.)  But all told, Flex is probably the least-limiting, most flexible, most feature-rich and productive option out there right now, so it's certainly worth considering.  Good luck!

Comment: @"No more debugging old versions of Netscape and IE": if something is developed in js-css it does not have to work on all browsers. All it takes is to pick one browser (Chrome, FireFox or latest IE) and go with it for all internal systems. js-css is good development platform if not spoiled by requirement to support all browsers and using heavy framework to compensate that unnecessary burden.

Answer (score 2):

Any javascript you have that has been developed 'Over the years' probably doesn't look anything like what's possible today. You undoubtedly have a lot of useful code there. nonetheless. So my recommendation would be re-write in javascript using jQuery and make use of one of the available GUI add-ons, perhaps look at Yahoos stuff. You will also be targeting the widest audience this way.

Answer (score 1):

The GUI technology should be first and foremost determined by your target audience. For instance, if you target englobes iPhone users, I would not recommend Flex, because iPhone doesn't have a flash player at the moment.

Bear in mind that if you switch to a full fledged GUI toolkit like Silverlight, your users may find the L&F unnatural, since the usual request-reply cycle is not so evident with client-side frameworks.

After that, it is your developers that should have a word to say. Every toolkit needs maintenance, and if you are switching to a whole new toolkit the developers will have to familiarize with the new toolkit, which can be costly.

My suggestion is that you stick to javascript, since your devs are familiar with it, and gradually replace the old javascript with a new toolkit like prototype, jQuery or any other. You will probably redo some of the old stuff faster using a state-of-the-art toolkit. Remember that you can build beautiful apps with any tookit.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [comparison table](http://askmeflash.com/article_m.php?p=article&id=11) for Flex vs Javascript:

Answer (score 1):

We have developed an extremely rich application using EXTJS with C# and a some C++ on the server. Not only do we have clients who are happy with the interface in their desktop browsers but with very little tweaking to the Javascript we were able to provide web browser support. Also, we have clients in third-world countries who cannot use Flash or Silverlight apps due to their field personnel using kiosks in internet cafes (many of which don't have Flash installed - forget Silverlight!). I think these issues and others make up for the difficulty of coding a complex app in javascript...